# How to reuse the variable used for for loop first level inside for loop second level in nested for loop

Tags: java

Someone can tell me how can I reuse rootOpt object inside of my forEach. Is there any way to reuse this variable? I have the following message "Can not resolve symbol rootOpt" when I write rootOpt.getChildOptions() inside my forEach. Please find below what I did:
I have tried to rewrite the for loop below by using stream. Thank you

```
opts.stream()
                .flatMap(rootOpt -> rootOpt.getChildOptions().stream())
                .forEach(subOpt -> {
                    if (subOpt.getOptLogic() != null && subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant() != null && !"".equals(subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant())) {
                        String[] oldCHs = subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant().split("( )");
                        OptionList samePriceSibs = getSamePriceS(rootOpt.getChildOptions(), subOpt);
                        for (String ch : oldCHs) {
                            Option chRootOpt = childOptCodeToParentOptMap.get(ch.toUpperCase());
                            if (chRootOpt != null) {
                                if (!DoesVariableOptionsCompletelyExcludeOther(samePriceSibs, chRootOpt.getChildOptions())) {
                                    List<OptionList> tmp = new ArrayList<OptionList>();
                                    tmp.add(samePriceSibs);
                                    tmp.add(chRootOpt.getChildOptions());
                                    optionsPairsToRemoveCHs.add(tmp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            for (Option rootOpt : opts) {
                for (Option subOpt : rootOpt.getChildOptions()) {
                    if (subOpt.getOptLogic() != null && subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant() != null && !"".equals(subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant())) {
                        String[] oldCHs = subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant().split("( )");
                        OptionList samePriceSibs = getSamePriceS(rootOpt.getChildOptions(), subOpt);
                        for (String ch : oldCHs) {
                            Option chRootOpt = childOptCodeToParentOptMap.get(ch.toUpperCase());
                            if (chRootOpt != null) {
                                if (!DoesVariableOptionsCompletelyExcludeOther(samePriceSibs, chRootOpt.getChildOptions())) {
                                    List<OptionList> tmp = new ArrayList<OptionList>();
                                    tmp.add(samePriceSibs);
                                    tmp.add(chRootOpt.getChildOptions());
                                    optionsPairsToRemoveCHs.add(tmp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This code looks unnecessarily complex. I'd refactor it into several methods.

Comment: Yep, 3 nested for loops with 3 conditionals have a high cyclomatic complexity. Move the bodies of ifs and fors to private methods and you'll see how your problem becomes clearer and you won't have that syntax error any more.

Comment: Complex. And unless opts is bigger than 10K, slow. Streams break even around that point

Comment: @efekctive Interesting... Where did you get that metric from? I'm not critisizing your comment, on the contrary, I would like to find a test or empiric evidence of your claim.

Comment: On SO. There are a couple of well researched, measured metrics about this. Both from this year. Don't have the links

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `rootOpt` ends at the closing parenthesis.
You could write it like this instead

```
opts.stream().forEach(rootOpt ->
  rootOpt.getChildOptions().stream().forEach(subOpt -> {
    ...
  });
);
```

However streams were not really intended to simply replace for loops. A more canonical way of using them would be something like this.

```
Stream<List<OptionList>> optionsPairsToRemoveCHs = opts.stream()
  .flatMap(rootOpt ->
    rootOpt.getChildOptions().stream()
           .filter(subOpt -> subOpt.getOptLogic() != null && subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant() != null && !"".equals(subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant()))
           .flatMap(subOpt -> {
              String[] oldCHs = subOpt.getOptLogic().getCant().split("( )");
              OptionList samePriceSibs = getSamePriceS(rootOpt.getChildOptions(), subOpt);
              return Stream.of(oldCHs)
                           .map(ch -> childOptCodeToParentOptMap.get(ch.toUpperCase()))
                           .filter(chRootOpt -> chRootOpt != null && !DoesVariableOptionsCompletelyExcludeOther(samePriceSibs, chRootOpt.getChildOptions()))
                           .map(chRootOpt -> Arrays.asList(samePriceSibs, chRootOpt.getChildOptions()));
           })
  );
```

I didn't test that code though. Also refactoring it into several methods as mike suggested would help making it easier to read.

Comment: My answer felt incomplete, so I added another solution.

Comment: Thank you so much every one. I am going to try both solutions: refactoring and SpiderPig code above and try to mesure the time it takes to process it. My question is, is splitting the code in different methods improve perfomance(I now it makes the code more readable but for me it should be the same in terme of performance no? Please correct me if I am wrong). My last question is for SpiderPig, The result of your code above is Stream<List<OptionList>> but how can I get a List<List<OptionList>> from this Stream<List<OptionList>> ? Thank you very much everyone

Comment: Ihave tried this Stream<List<OptionList>> optionsPairsToRemoveCHs = optionsPairsToRemoveCHsStream.collect(Collectors.toList()); to convert the stream to List. Please correct me if it is wrong

Comment: Yes using `Collectors.toList` is the normal way of converting a Stream to a List. Btw. you don't have to decide between my code and refactoring. You can do both by for example writing a method that you then pass into `flatMap`. If you want to improve performance you can simply parallel the code i.e. making it run on several cores. All you need to do is add `.parallel()` after `opts.stream()` and it will automatically run on multiple cores. And it will be completely thread safe as long as all the methods you call in that code are thread safe.